# Best Rigorous Introduction to Music Theory?

Tags: self-learning, teaching

I've been pretty intensively playing classical and jazz trumpet (albeit as a hobbyist) for about 13 years, and I've been wanting to get into composition. I haven't had too much training in music theory aside from a few jazz lessons and whatever you'd passively pick up from playing, and I was looking for a good, rigorous introduction to the study. Does anyone have any recommendations for resources I can look into?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Requests for specific resources are outside of the [topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but if you edit the question simply to focus on "how do I go about it" that's fine. My best advice would be to actually audit a college or high school "theory 101" course; second best would be to use one of the textbooks commonly used in such courses. Steve Laitz's *The Complete Musician* was published after my time, but his in-person classes were great. [MusicTheory.net](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons) can be confusing, but is a good crash course.

Comment: Resource requests are offside here, sorry. But a good plan could be to look through some exam syllabi - ABRSM, for example. Not clear whether it's classical or jazz theory you need.

Answer (score 1):

I know little about jazz theory though I have studied lots of Common-Practice-Period music procedures. If you plan on self-study, I'd suggest checking out some free (or cheap from used book stores) texts. CPP theory is mostly about, "This is what has been done. If you find a pattern you think sounds good, this is the way it was accomplished." Some turn of the (20th) century texts are pretty good though seeming old-fashioned; you have to interpret things in a way that helps your music. The good news is that there are quite a few texts with differing viewpoints. I like Frank Shephard's "Harmony Simplified" and "How to Modulate" for one point of view. Francis York's "Harmony Simplified" and "Counterpoint Simplified" are good too; his approach is slightly different from Shepards. Percy Goetschius has lots of books; the only ones I like are "Exercises in Melody Writing" and "Applied Counterpoint." His books on music basics and harmony tend to be differently organized from that of other authors.

There are modern texts; I like Paul Harder's "Harmonic Materials of Tonal Music" which are programmed learning-oriented. I think someone else has taken over authorship. Other good modern texts will probably be recommended as well as some jazz-oriented theory.

Another nice exercise is to take a piece (any genre) that you like and make a copy by hand (actually, one should use a computer notation program.) By going through pieces in this much detail, one gets a better understanding of the compositional procedures used.